# Changing Time To A Comparable Function In R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in .csv, and I have added in a column on my own in the csv that takes the **total time taken** for a task to be completed. There are two other columns that consists of the **start time** and the **end time**, and that is where I calculated the **total time taken** column from. The format of the **start time** and **end time** columns are in the datetime format 5/7/2018 16:13 while the format of the **total time taken** column is 0:08:20(H:MM:SS).

I understand that for datetime, it is possible to use the functions as.Date or as.POSIXlt to change the variable type from a factor to that of date. Is there a function that I can convert my **total time taken** column to (from that of factor) so that I can use it to plot scatterplots/plots in general? I tried as.numeric but the numbers that come out are gibberish and do not correspond to the original time.

Comment: Hello and welcoem to Stack Overflow! Please show us your current efforts to solve your question! Not only it saves our time, but it also shwos you made some effort to solve it before posting here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot the total time taken for each row, then I would suggest just plotting that difference as seconds.  Here is a code snippet which shows how you can convert your start or end date into a numerical value:

```
start <- "5/7/2018 16:13"
start_date <- as.POSIXct(start, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
as.numeric(start_date)

[1] 1530799980
```

The above is a UNIX timestamp, which is number of seconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970).  But, since you want a difference between start and end times, this detail does not really matter for you, and the difference you get should be valid.

If you want to use minutes, hours, or some other time unit, then you can easily convert.